Testdome Reactjs GroceryApp Component Question
You have a GroceryApp component, which receives a list of products, each one with name and votes. The app should render an unordered list, with a list item for each product.
Products can be upvoted or downvoted.
By appropriately using React state and props, implement the upvote/ downvote logic. Keep the state in the topmost component, while the Product component should accept props.
For example, passing the following array as products prop to GroceryApp [{ name: "Oranges", votes: 0}, { name: "Bananas", votes: 0 }] and clicking the 't' button next to the Oranges should result in HTML like:
‹div id="root"›
   ‹ul>
     ‹li›
       ‹ span›Oranges</span> - ‹span›votes: 1</span>
       ‹button >+‹/button> ‹button>-</button>
     ‹/li>
     ‹ li >
       ‹span>Bananas</span> - ‹span>votes: 0‹/ span>
       ‹button >+</button> ‹button>-</button>
     ‹/li>
   </ul>
‹/div›


Answer::
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const Product = props => {
  const plus = () => {
    props.onVote('+', props.index)
  };
  const minus = () => {
    props.onVote('-', props.index)
  };
  
  return (
    <li>
      <span>{props.prod.name}</span> - <span>votes: {props.prod.votes}</span>
      <button onClick={plus}>+</button>{" "}
      <button onClick={minus}>-</button>
    </li>
  );
};

const GroceryApp = (props) => {
  let [products, setProducts] = React.useState(props.products);
  const onVote = (dir, index) => {
    let newProducts = [...products]
    if(dir === '-'){
      newProducts[index].votes--
    }
    else if(dir === '+'){
      newProducts[index].votes++
    }
    setProducts(newProducts)
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      { 
        products.map((prod, i)=> <Product key={prod.name+"#"+i} prod={prod} index={i} onVote={onVote}/> )
      }
    </ul>
  );
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'></div>";
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<GroceryApp
  products={[
    { name: "Oranges", votes: 0 },
    { name: "Bananas", votes: 0 }
  ]}
/>);

setTimeout(() => {
  let plusButton = document.querySelector("ul > li > button");
  if(plusButton) {
    plusButton.click();
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(document.getElementById('root').outerHTML);
  });
});

